# Creation of enumerate-like enviroment in gather and align environments

Tags: amsmath, enumerate

I use the `gather` and `align`-`aligned` environments of `amsmath` package and I want to create a list inside them like the one created with the `enumerate` environment. How can I achieve that?

A MWE would be that:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&x+y=0\\
&y+z=0\\
&z+x=0
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\everymath{\displaymath}`. It's wrong and it will bite you some day.

Comment: @egreg I use it because in the past I was placing `\displaystyle` everywhere and this is helping very much. I like having this style everywhere.

Comment: It's wrong to be placing `\displaystyle` everywhere to begin with.

Comment: I understand that it might be wrong but I am not using it to produce a book or a paper. I use it for notes or for exercises that I want to read again so it helps me even though it might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an `aligned` *within* an enumaerated list

[image]

otherwise, you should really use the equation numbering built into `align`:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use a custom macro such as `\Item` below which increments a counter and add is its value before the equation to emulate *sort of* a `enumerate` type of environment. I am recommending you *not* use this as I am sure there are numerous problems with it, even though it appears to work for the test case given.

[image]

---

### Code: `Recommended`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta &= 1 \\
        F &= ma 
      \end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
        E &= mc^2 \\
        \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta &= 1
      \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
%
\begin{align}
        \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta &= 1 \\
        F &= ma \\
        E &= mc^2 \\
        \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta &= 1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `Custom "enumerate":

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\everymath{\displaystyle}
%\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\newcommand{\Item}{\refstepcounter{MyCounter}\theMyCounter\quad}
\renewcommand{\theMyCounter}{\arabic{MyCounter})}
\newcommand{\ResetMyCounter}{\setcounter{MyCounter}{0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &x+y=0\\
        \Item &y+z=0\\
        \Item &z+x=0
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
And in a subsequent set of equations  \emph{with} \verb|\ResetMyCounter|:
\ResetMyCounter% Comment this out if you wish the numbering to continue
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &x+y=0\\
        \Item &y+z=0\\
        \Item &z+x=0
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
And in a subsequent set of equations \emph{without} \verb|\ResetMyCounter|:
%\ResetMyCounter% Comment this out if you wish the numbering to continue
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &x+y=0\\
        \Item &y+z=0\\
        \Item &z+x=0
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
With a \verb|\renewcommand| to use non-numerical numbering:
\renewcommand{\theMyCounter}{\alph{MyCounter}.\quad}
\ResetMyCounter% Comment this out if you wish the numbering to continue
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &x+y=0\\
        \Item &y+z=0\\
        \Item &z+x=0
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Athough these are good solutions they are not exactly helpful because I use a lot of consecutive blocks and the first solution would mean that I have to break the one `gather` into two and the second  would suggest that all my equations should be numbered and not only a fraction of them. And I would like the number in front.

Comment: @Adam: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem, and gives us something to work with.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't do that, I just thought that because this is a general question that anyone can check without a MWE, my code would only confuse.

Comment: @Adam: Ok, have provided an alternate - Like I mention in the solution, I am _not_ recommending this approach, but this should get you started in the direction I think you want to go,

Comment: Thank you I think that your second solution is what I was looking for. I will try it further to see if it suits me!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comments to Peter Grill's answer, you want to label some (not all) of your equations and label them on the left. For the small example you give, I think this does roughly what you want, by using `leqno` in the `documentclass` and using `align` rather than `aligned` inside `gather` and setting `\notag` for lines you don't want to have a number.

However, there is probably some good reason why you can't use `align` or something, that is not clear from your question.

Also, I'm not sure how to get rid of the parentheses around the equation number label if you really want it to look like enumerate.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\begin{align}
&x+y=0 \\
\intertext{no eq number for the next one} \notag
&y+z=0 \notag \\
&z+x=0 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is just a MWE. My code has a lot of blocks and I want all of my equations without numbers. Sometimes I want something like the `enumerate` environment. with this solution every equation will have a tag and only the ones that I mark are going to be free of tags which is not a good and easy way. Not to mention that my doal is not to tag certain equations. But thank you anyway for your solution!

Comment: @Adam, I suspected as much but as I said it is not really clear from your very minimal example what you actually need to do. Can I suggest you post a more full example (or maybe a png of how you want the numbering from a mock-up in word or something) if Bernard's answer below doesn't help you because I still don't really understand exactly what you want!

Comment: Thank you for your help. The second solution that Peter provided is, I think, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the `newtagform` from  `\mathtools`. With the `fleqn` option, you have to re-define the values of `\mathindent` to have the number on the same line as the equation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}%
\newtagform{enum}{\hskip\parindent}{. }
\setlength{\mathindent}{\dimexpr\leftmargini + \parindent\relax}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{enum}
This is an example.
\begin{align}
&x+y=0 \\
\intertext{no eq number for the next one:}  \notag
&y+z=0 \notag \\
&z+x=0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]